# Loop filter of PLL

Tags: filter

For an RC low pass filter as shown we give input to the resistor and check output across the capacitor. 
[image: RC filter]

But how do we check the frequency response of a loop filter in a PLL which is a low pass filter? Here it is as though both input and output is connected to a wire, or is my interpretation wrong? Where do we give input and where to take the output from?
[image: Loop filter]

Comment: Read  answer from            Andy aka and revise thevanin and norton and then you will get it .This loop configurement is common so you should get a handle on it .

Comment: Hint : a current source has a high output impedance. Find out what that impedance is, and use its value for the R in your first circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nice thing (for certain meanings of nice) about PLLs is that the loop filter must not contain an integrator, at least, not at the loop bandwidth. As the VCO is already an integrator, and as other components will add a bit more phase shift, a simple second integrator would guarrantee instability by giving you 180 degrees plus a bit of phase shift.

What you have there is a very standard loop filter, when used with a current output phase detector.

You can make a stable and reasonably performing loop by simplifying it down to use an infinite Cz, and a zero Cp. Then the circuit reduces to simply Rz. This defines the gain of your loop, and so defines the loop bandwidth, the frequency where the closed loop gain is unity.

Now you have a stable loop of the right bandwidth, you will probably want to add some low pass filtering at high frequencies, to reduce reference noise and PSD breakthrough. This is OK once you are well above the loop bandwidth, say by a factor of 3 or so. Increase Cp until its time constant with Rz gives you a pole at >= 3 times loop bandwidth.

You will probably also want to add some integration at low frequency, so your loop tracks without long term phase error, and to suppress close in VCO noise. This is OK once you are well below the loop bandwidth, say by a factor of 3 or so. Decrease Cz down from infinity until its time constant with Rz gives you a zero at <= 30% of the loop bandwidth.

So because of the severe restriction of <<90 degrees phase shift at the loop bandwidth, the loop design is easy. Choose loop bandwidth. Choose Rz (in conjunction with PSD gain and VCO gain) to give you that loop bandwidth. Choose Cp and Cz to give you breaks above and below the loop bandwidth respectively.

Answer (score 4):

The big thing that you are not realising is that in your second circuit, the signal source is a current and not a voltage. This is fairly standard in many PLLs. Try modelling the circuit in something like LTSpice and you will see that it behaves appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

second pole is to reduce the forward feedthrough of noise. But intuitively, second pole must have R and C but this looks like standard way of adding only C , so is the confusion. Basically they are trying to bring a pole beyond Wu,loop frequency to reduce the noise (forward feedthrough) passing from one stage to another.

Answer (score 0):

This a classic lag-lead compensator intended for a current pump phase detector. This gives added phase margin for stability at unity gain bandwidth frequency.  Often C ratio are 10:1 for small R.

Since this converts I(t) to V(t) , you can insert a unity gain noninverting buffer to inject additional V(f) sweep and measure error response from V(t) such that levels do not become non-linear with a tracking filter and peak detector.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5nY5g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: is there anything particular regarding the specification of the opamp that is to be used there as buffer?

Comment: highZin and non-inverting is all.  There are other ways with 1 OA using gain 1/2 then x2, but Vref must be the same Vc when locked usually Vdd/2